# Disable edit is not working

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, searchbar

I am working with `ion-searchbar`, i need to disable the edit mode of `ion-searchbar`.

**My code snippet -**

```
<ion-searchbar  [disabled]="true"  style="padding: 0" class="add-place-item-divider" [(ngModel)]="mainTrail.source"></ion-searchbar>
```

But the above code is not working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Please use the css property **pointer-events: none;**, I modified your code. Please replace it with the below one

```
<ion-searchbar  style="pointer-events: none;padding: 0" class="add-place-item-divider" [(ngModel)]="mainTrail.source"></ion-searchbar>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, it works. Do you know how to enable / disable the searchbar from the component?

Comment: For enable and disable from the component means need a clear info or post a new question and add that link in the comment, I will look into that and will help you to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The disable attribute on the Searchbar is not passed to the inner `input` element. I guess we could hack the DOM view ViewChild of ViewChildren...

But there is also a way to use Ganesh Pediredla's idea and implement a method to enable/disable the component based on the `pointer-events` CSS property.

Use a property to enable or disable a CSS class declaring `pointer-events: none;padding:`

HTML

```
<ion-searchbar [ngClass]="{ 'no-pointer-events': disableSearchbar }" class="add-place-item-divider" [(ngModel)]="mainTrail.source"></ion-searchbar>
```

CSS

```
.no-pointer-events {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Component

```
public disableSearchbar: boolean = true;

toggleSearchbar(status: boolean): void {
    this.disableSearchbar = !this.disableSearchbar;
}
```

[See in in action on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-w9uicr)